# Creating staggered Card in android

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I am in need of doing a layout which I don't understand how to proceed with

[image]

How to create such pointers type grid of card?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of doing this is using a RecyclerView. To the RecyclerView you set a layout manager and then treat it as any other RecyclerView/Listview (set adapter). Basically like this:

```
mStaggeredLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredLayoutManager);
```

The contents in each row will have to be different heights to give the staggered look, otherwise it will look just like a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to use the new [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), setting a [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) will accomplish what you need.

[Video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYsO_h6I_Hw)

[Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)